Science fiction anthology of short stories about radiation and nuclear disasters
I read this book when I was a kid in the 90s. I think it may have been stories all by the same author, who I think was a woman, but I’m not sure.
The only story I remember in any detail was about cancer patients at a hospital. When they died, they were being buried in a graveyard outside of the hospital for some reason. Eventually, the graves started growing giant glowing mushrooms.
I think there was another story in the aftermath of the Three Mile Island accident. It might have been about a pilot flying over.
